# Rigidy body for an animated mesh with curve

Tags: modifiers, physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody, curve-modifier

I would like that these rigid body spheres to interact with this mesh animated object, how is it possible?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just change your animated mesh to "passive" and check "deforming"

result:

[image]